# Problem saving information from csv file to C array

Tags: c

I must read the information contained within an external file in .csv format and I must save each row of the file in an array. The code I have to perform that action is the following:

```
int generate_matrix(char *filename){

FILE *input1 = fopen(filename,"r");

if(input1 == NULL){
            
    return 1;
}

//counts the number of rows the file contains
int rows = 1;

char c = fgetc(input1);

while(!feof(input1)){
    
    if(c == '\n') rows++;
    
    c = fgetc(input1);
}

fclose(input1);

FILE *input2 = fopen(filename,"r");

char *students[rows];

char row[1000];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    
    fgets(row,1000,input2);
    
    row[strlen(row)] = '\0';
    
    students[i] = row;
    
    printf("%s", students[i]);
    
}

fclose(input2);

printf("\n\n");

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    printf("%s\n", students[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

This code is what is supposed to read the turn line in the file and save it in the corresponding position of the array:

```
FILE *input2 = fopen(filename,"r");

char *students[rows];

char row[1000];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    
    fgets(row,1000,input2);
    
    row[strlen(row)] = '\0';
    
    students[i] = row;
    
    printf("%s", students[i]);
    
}
```

At the end of each turn of the loop, I print the value that studenst [i] takes and it actually reads line by line and apparently the code does its job. This is the output of the program so far:

```
,TheGodfather,TokyoDrift,SpiritedAway,Tenet,TheGrandBudapestHotel,Frozen
ph20003,0,1,0,1,1,0
fc20015,1,1,0,1,0,0
cm19086,1,1,1,0,0,1
ve20008,0,1,0,1,0,0
mf19026,1,1,1,0,1,1
rc19106,0,0,1,1,0,1
ag19101,0,0,0,0,0,0
pg19065,0,1,0,0,0,0
lr19047,1,1,1,0,0,1
rf18025,0,1,0,0,0,0
aa19091,1,0,1,1,0,1
cc19089,0,1,1,1,0,0
hs20006,1,1,1,1,1,1
av19023,0,1,1,0,0,1
ft19004,0,0,0,0,0,1
dg17019,1,1,0,0,0,1
aa20047,0,1,0,0,0,0
rc19102,1,1,0,0,0,1
gr20035,1,0,1,0,0,0
rm19021,0,0,0,0,0,1
tq19002,0,1,0,0,0,1
ag17057,0,0,1,0,0,1
pc19060,1,1,1,0,0,1
hr18024,0,1,1,0,0,1
pm20072,1,1,0,0,0,1
tc20006,0,1,1,1,0,1
va17017,0,1,0,0,0,1
am18007,1,0,1,0,0,0
sm18038,0,1,0,0,0,0
cc20019,0,0,1,0,0,1
ff18023,0,1,0,0,0,0
vc17044,0,1,0,0,0,0
jm17015,0,1,0,1,0,1
ha19027,0,1,0,1,0,0
cd20017,0,1,1,0,0,1
mp19034,1,1,0,1,0,0
le19005,0,0,0,0,0,0
ma19074,0,1,0,0,0,1
cf20014,0,1,0,0,0,0
am19139,0,1,0,0,0,1
qj20001,0,0,0,0,0,0
pa19031,0,1,0,0,0,1
gs20027,0,1,1,0,0,1
ot20006,0,1,1,1,1,1
ze17002,0,1,1,0,0,1
ga19038,0,1,0,0,0,0
mh19029,0,1,0,0,0,1
fb19009,1,1,1,0,1,0
om20022,0,0,0,0,0,0
jg11008,0,1,1,0,0,0
gr12043,0,1,1,0,0,0
ar14078,0,1,1,0,0,1
vc20009,0,1,0,0,0,1
fa20011,0,1,0,0,0,0
mh19062,0,0,0,0,0,1
pr20028,0,0,0,0,1,1
ha17010,0,1,0,0,0,0
er20001,0,1,0,1,1,1
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

The problem is that when I end the loop to display the information, it prints repeated information, as if I had only read a single record.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    printf("%s\n", students[i]);
}
```

The result of the above is:

```
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0 
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0 
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

Corresponds to the last record in the file. I do not know why it is behaving that way, I do not know if it is something that I do not know about the fgets function or what. I appreciate your help

Comment: You only have a single `row` array and you make all the pointers stored in `student` point to that one. That is obviously not what you intended, you need to look into dynamic memory allocations and/or `strdup`

Comment: You don't need to read the file to determine the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You are pointing every row in *students[row] to row[1000]. "row" was created on the stack and has an **address** and a **value**. when you set
`students[i] = row` you are setting the value of the pointer at index i in students[] to the address of "row". The value of a Pointer is the memory address of a variable and not the value of what the variable was at the time you assigned it to the pointer. So since every pointer in Students[] points to "row" then with every loop the value that each pointer would print changes every time you change what the value of "row" is.

Here is what a few iterations of the for loop looks like. I made up the addresses.

```
Iteration       Variable Name       Address             Value
1rst loop       row                 0x7ffc2ede6efc      ph20003,0,1,0,1,1,0
                student[0]          0x8ffc2ede6f4f      0x7ffc2ede6efc
```

print student[0] will output "ph20003,0,1,0,1,1,0"

```
Iteration       Variable Name       Address             Value
2nd loop        row                 0x7ffc2ede6efc      fc20015,1,1,0,1,0,0  
                student[1]          0x6ffc2ede6f84      0x7ffc2ede6efc
```

print student[1] will output "fc20015,1,1,0,1,0,0"

Since student[0]'s value is also the address of "row" 
printing student[0] will also output "fc20015,1,1,0,1,0,0"

This is why when you print it out at the end you are printing the same thing over and over again. Every pointer in the Students[] array is pointed at the same variable.

## Solution

There are a number of ways you could go about fixing this issue. With the way you are trying to store the lines into *students[] you will need to allocate memory for every row using malloc (memory allocate).

```
size_t bufsize = 1000;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   students[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
   getline(&students[i], &bufsize, input1);
}
```

this will allocate 1000 bytes of size char for every row and then store the line read into that row. The only thing is that when you are done you should create a cleanup function or for loop and free all the memory that you allocated.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   printf("%s\n", students[i]);
   free(students[i]);
}
fclose(input1);
return 0;
```

You also don't need to close your file and reopen it to get back to the beginning, you can just use fseek(). You just pass it the pointer to the file, number of positions you want to seek, and where you would like to seek from. There are three options for the third argument. You can start from the beginning of the file by passing SEEK_SET, from the current position of the file by passing SEEK_CUR, and from the end of the file by passing SEEK_END. To reset back to the beginning you just say you want to move 0 positions from the beginning of the file.

```
fseek(input1, 0, SEE_SET);
```

That's it. You're back at the beginning and can start your for loop. Lastly since this is a csv file you more than likely have to read in each string and number in each row individually into its own spot in generate_matrix, you should look into strtok. after reading in a line you can use strtok and set the delimiter as "," and use it to read the first string and then every number in the row.